# List do not inherit fields from content type

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, content-type, inheritance, custom-content-type

I have an issue when I create a content type, and it properly is created on the site but is not working at all on list.

I used `Sharepoint Manager 2010` to watch web internals and here I am.

Here is content type as declared in solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <!-- Measure: Item (0x01) -->
  <ContentType ID="0x01004e96b35503e747efb4d27edab8777999"
               Name="$Resources:Type_Measure;"
               Group="$Resources:Type_Group;"
               Description="$Resources:Type_Measure_Description;"
               Inherits="FALSE" 
               Version="0">
    <FieldRefs>
      <FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Hidden="TRUE" Required="FALSE" DisplayName="_hiddenTitle" />
      <FieldRef ID="{E52EF588-03DE-44a6-84D9-9E0FD25F11C0}" Name="Measure_Test" />     
    </FieldRefs>
  </ContentType>

  <Field ID="{E52EF588-03DE-44a6-84D9-9E0FD25F11C0}"
         Name="Measure_Test"
         StaticName="Measure_Test"
         DisplayName="Measure_Test"
         Group="$Resources:Field_Measure_Group;"
         Type="Boolean" />
</Elements>
```

`Inherit=TRUE` do not change this behaviour.

Here is content type definition from web's `AvailableContentTypes` node:

```
  <ContentType ID="0x01004E96B35503E747EFB4D27EDAB8777999" Name="Мера" Group="Some" Version="0" FeatureId="{c32e3c2a-66c3-4466-a5e1-a248daa44499}">
    <Folder TargetName="_cts/Мера" />
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}" Name="ContentType" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ContentType" Group="_Hidden" Type="Computed" DisplayName="Тип контента" Sealed="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" RenderXMLUsingPattern="TRUE" PITarget="MicrosoftWindowsSharePointServices" PIAttribute="ContentTypeID" Customization="">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef ID="{03e45e84-1992-4d42-9116-26f756012634}" Name="ContentTypeId" />
        </FieldRefs>
        <DisplayPattern>
          <MapToContentType>
            <Column Name="ContentTypeId" />
          </MapToContentType>
        </DisplayPattern>
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" Group="_Hidden" Type="Text" DisplayName="_hiddenTitle" Required="FALSE" FromBaseType="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" Customization="" />
      <Field ID="{E52EF588-03DE-44a6-84D9-9E0FD25F11C0}" Name="Measure_Test" StaticName="Measure_Test" DisplayName="Measure_Test" Group="Some" Type="Boolean" Customization="">
      </Field>
    </Fields>
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
        <FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
          <Display>ListForm</Display>
          <Edit>ListForm</Edit>
          <New>ListForm</New>
        </FormTemplates>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
```

And here is definition in List.

```
  <ContentType ID="0x01004E96B35503E747EFB4D27EDAB877799900C44DB4DB0CADDE43AE87AFB9E482E1D5" Name="Мера" Group="Some" Description="" Inherits="FALSE" Version="0" FeatureId="{c32e3c2a-66c3-4466-a5e1-a248daa44499}">
    <Fields>
      <Field ID="{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}" Type="Computed" DisplayName="Тип контента" Name="ContentType" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" RenderXMLUsingPattern="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ContentType" Group="_Hidden" PITarget="MicrosoftWindowsSharePointServices" PIAttribute="ContentTypeID" FromBaseType="TRUE">
        <FieldRefs>
          <FieldRef Name="ContentTypeId" />
        </FieldRefs>
        <DisplayPattern>
          <MapToContentType>
            <Column Name="ContentTypeId" />
          </MapToContentType>
        </DisplayPattern>
      </Field>
      <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Type="Text" Name="Title" DisplayName="_hiddenTitle" Required="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" FromBaseType="TRUE" ColName="nvarchar1" Hidden="TRUE" />
    </Fields>
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
        <FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
          <Display>ListForm</Display>
          <Edit>ListForm</Edit>
          <New>ListForm</New>
        </FormTemplates>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
```

As you can see, at last step this field (and all others when added) just disappears and I don't know why and how to fix it. Please, advice.

---

I have another similar list with content type and it works fine. I found that problem could be in `<Folder TargetName="XYZ" />` tag which is missing in `not working` case.

Comment: Why are you using a different ID in the list? Use the same one: 0x01004e96b35503e747efb4d27edab8777999. SharePoint will manage the inheritance on it's own.

Comment: It IS managed by sharepoint, it's a simple guid inheritance, and I wrote only first markup. 2nd and 3rd are generated by sharepoint, based on this content type.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out, as I thought these were snippets from the definitions made by you.

Comment: No problem. And there is something interesting: it doesn't work from schema, but when I remove and add content type for a list, all fields appears. So it's possible to make it work manually, but isn't from the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an answer: it's because of `Title` field. I tried to hide it by using another fild with same GUID as default `Title` column, but it seems that SharePoint is going crazy when I do such stuff. So i removed this field and content type properly worked to me. Well, I will remove this column from the code.